# Separate Cloudant Service from Bluemix

Tags: mongodb, heroku, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I was hosting my node app on Heroku connected to a mongolab for the DB.
Thanks to a few tips from here, I've deployed my app code to Bluemix.  I moved mainly because I'm changing databases from mongodb to couchdb, and am hoping that Bluemix might have a faster connection due the relationship they have as both being IBM services.

Ok, now for the questions :p

First, since Cloudant was added to my app as a "service" it was generically provisioned and hence the username/pass/etc were generated.  I assume I can also simply create my own separate Cloudant account and put an all of its settings into my Bluemix app manually.  So, if I was to do that, to separately link up a separate Cloudantdb to my Bluemix app, would it be slightly slower or have any other negatives?  I'm asking because maybe when it's auto-provisioned (and all done together), maybe it is configured in a way with few network hops/firewalls are skipped between the connections.  Remember my initial motivation for trying out Bluemix was due to its relationship with Cloudant.

Second, if I decided to just stick with the auto-provisioned Cloudant db, how can I change the username?  I've been playing with the interface and don't see that option anywhere.  If I can or can't, I assume that I should be able to point my separate Heroku app to it using the same credentials Bluemix uses and it should work the same (as a separate db, just like I do with my single Mongolab and various PAAS providers).

Thanks for the info!
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can surely create your own separate Cloudant account, and then enter all of its settings into your Bluemix app manually. The connection speed would depend on your choice of data center locations (SoftLayer, Rackspace or Azure) when you created your Cloudant account. If you choose a SoftLayer data center, the speed would be faster than if you have chosen Rackspace or Azure due to the high-speed private network between all the SoftLayer data centers.

I'm not aware of a way to change usernames after it has been provisioned. You should be able to use those same credentials to point your Heroku app to.

Comment: Just to add something to what Charles said.  You cannot change the username and password auto generated by Cloudant when you bind the service to your app.  You can however launch the Cloudant dashboard and  go to the permissions section for any database and create new API Keys and Secrets for other apps to access that database.  Unfortunately these are auto-generated as well.  You can read more about this here https://cloudant.com/for-developers/faq/auth/.

Comment: You don't have to use the automatically bound credentials.  You can follow a similar approach to this to manage credentials: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/171072/migrating-a-bluemix-cloudant-multi-tenant-account.html